# How do I convert array of objects to object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects:

```
let userDetail = [{id: "12347442", name: "ZarNi" , age: 23}
{id: "2435457", name: "Michael" , age: 13},
{id: "8639503", name: "John" , age: 18}
]
```

I filtered this array into this:

```
let filteredUser = userDetail.filter(user => user.id === "12347442");
```

I need to put object to react state. so I've written like this:

```
this.setState({user: {...filteredUser}});
```

When I took the console for user state,I've got the result like this:

```
console.log(this.state.user);

Result => {0:{id: "12347442", name: "ZarNi" , age: 23}} as a result;
```

I don't want Key 0. I just want to get object like this

```
{id: "12347442", name: "ZarNi" , age: 23}
```

Comment: userDetail[0] not working?

Comment: why not take the object with an index?

Comment: const [obj] = yourArray;

Comment: this.setState({user: {...filteredUser[0]}});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the records in your array have different IDs OR you expect to use the first match anyway, it's not `filter` you need - but `find`:

```
// const, as you're not expected to change value of that variable
const foundUser = userDetail.find(user => user.id === "12347442");
```

In this case you won't even have to worry about extracting the first element from that array which is result of `filter` op - and pass that user into setState directly.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `find`

```
let userSelected = userDetail.find(x=>x.id === '12347442');
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed my code like this and I've got the result that I want.

```js
    let userDetail = [{id: "12347442", name: "ZarNi" , age: 23},
                      {id: "2435457", name: "Michael" , age: 13},
                      {id: "8639503", name: "John" , age: 18}];

    let user = userDetail.find(user => user.id === "12347442");
 
    this.setstate({user: user});
    console.log(this.state.user);
```

Result:

```
{id: "12347442", name: "ZarNi" , age: 23}
```

Comment: No offence, but this tremendously inefficient - and what's more important, not really readable. Why do you use `filter` when `find` is fit? Why do you copy your found object - not once, but twice? Do you know that with `...` you'll have only a shallow copy of an object? And why do you post your own code as an answer when it's essentially the same of one of existing ones?

Comment: These codes are both different a bit and not sufficient yet. Anyway, thanks man. I accept your suggestion. I am gotta change **filter** to **find** method.

Answer (score 0):

if your array length=1 you must get `userDetail[0]`

Comment: got it. Thanks for your help.